# Rounding and padding a decimal

Tags: c#, .net

Hello I have a decimal which I want to round and want to pad.

Is it possible to do this in one command

Rounding can be done as follows

```
 $"{myDecimal:F0}"
```

padding can be done as follows

```
$"{myDecimal:D6}"
```

is it possible to do both at once?

Here are some examples:

```
30 => 000030
30.02 => 000030
30.6 => 000031
30000 => 030000
```

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide 16 inputs, and the matching outputs you are hoping to achieve. Also please specify what type of rounding you are aiming for - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.midpointrounding.aspx .

Comment: Share some sample input and expected output too

Comment: so what should `30.60` be `000030` or `000031`? or for that matter what about `30.5`? Need more details

Comment: Why not simply `$"{myDecimal:000000}"`?

Comment: @Corak You should post that as the answer.

Comment: `D6` isn't even valid for a `decimal` type.

Comment: @Corak you're right. I've edited it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not restricted to the standard format specifiers. You can use [custom format specifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings) to create, well, custom formats. With the added bonus, that rounding (AFAIK "away from zero" by default) is already included.

So `F0` means: no decimal places (i.e. round to full integer) and `D6` (for integers, not for decimals; thanks juharr) means: fill up to six digits.

Which is what this custom format does "combined":

```
$"{myDecimal:000000}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Would that work for you?

```
$"{Math.Round(myDecimal):D6}"
```